# Unable to use php 8.1 after installing using macports, how do I solve this?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macports

I am working on **macOS 10.14 Mojave**

I am trying to work with **Symfony 6.3** which requires **PHP** version 8.1 and above. so I tried installing with `brew install php@8.1` but then I had an error with **openldap**:

> inreplace failed /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf:

so instead now have to install a new version of my PHP using **macports** which I have carried out successfully.

Problem is after run

```bash
sudo port select --list PHP
```

I can see php81 (active) but when I run

```bash
php-v
```

I get `PHP 7.1.23 (cli)`. But even then, when I try to run

```bash
brew uninstall php@7.1
```

I get:

> No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1

How do I switch to the new version of PHP 8.1 that installed using mac ports?

Comment: Sounds like something else installed PHPv7.
What does `which php-v` return? How about `type php-v`?
To my knowledge, PHP is not part of the base macOS install. You may need to purge your system of older PHP installations.
Also check your path: `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with openldap, which I solved by manually modifying the 2 files.

In the "/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf" file, I changed line 17 to "# modulepath /usr/local/Cellar/openldap/2.6.4/libexec/openldap".

In the "/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif" file, I changed line 32 to "#olcModulepath: /usr/local/Cellar/openldap/2.6.4/libexec/openldap".

Then the installation/upgrade works